# Text won't show up in LOVE2D game

Tags: text, lua, love2d

I am currently making my **Plants vs Zombies** using LOVE2D, only finishing the start state. The problem though is that option text won't show up, only the title does:

I made this in `StartState.lua`:

```
StartState = Class{__includes = BaseState}

local option = 1

function StartState:update(dt)
    if love.keyboard.wasPressed('up') then
        if option == 1 then
            option = 2
        else
            option = 1
        end
    elseif love.keyboard.wasPressed('down') then
        if option == 2 then
            option = 1
        else
            option = 2
        end
    end

    if love.keyboard.wasPressed('enter') then
        if option == 1 then
            gStateMachine:change('play')
        else
            gStateMachine:change('quit')
        end
    end
end

function StartState:render()
    local backgroundWidth = gTextures['start-background']:getWidth()
    local backgroundHeight = gTextures['start-background']:getHeight()

    love.graphics.draw(gTextures['start-background'], 0, 0, 0, VIRTUAL_WIDTH / (backgroundWidth - 1), 
        VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / (backgroundHeight - 1))

    love.graphics.setFont(gFonts['medium'])
    love.graphics.setColor(0/255, 0/255, 0/255, 255/255)
    love.graphics.printf('Play', 0, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT + 5, VIRTUAL_WIDTH + 2, 'center')
    love.graphics.printf('Quit', 0, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT + 35, VIRTUAL_WIDTH + 2, 'center')

    if option == 1 then
        love.graphics.setColor(255/255, 174/255, 201/255, 255/255)
        love.graphics.printf('Play', 0, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
        love.graphics.setColor(237/255, 28/255, 36/255, 255/255)
        love.graphics.printf('Quit', 0, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT + 30, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
    else
        love.graphics.setColor(237/255, 28/255, 36/255, 255/255)
        love.graphics.printf('Play', 0, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
        love.graphics.setColor(255/255, 174/255, 201/255, 255/255)
        love.graphics.printf('Quit', 0, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT + 30, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
    end

    love.graphics.setFont(gFonts['large'])
    love.graphics.setColor(153/255, 217/255, 234/255, 128/255)
    love.graphics.printf('Attack Them All', 0, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2 - 50, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')

    love.graphics.setColor(255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 255/255)
end
```

I even tried to get rid of the background to make sure if the text is at the back, but no, it is not there. I even tried changing the opacity, but still nothing. How do I fix it?

Comment: Do you crreate a StartState object and then call `StartState:update(dt)` or `StartState:render()`? It won't happen automatically. If you upload your whole game to a github I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look back at your coordinates of the text. If you see misleading coordinates, try fixing it!

Answer (score 1):

You can only draw objects at the [love.draw()](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.draw) callback, it must be executed periodically every time you want it to draw for the current frame

At your `main.lua` file:

```lua
function love.update()
    StartState:update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
    StartState:render()
end
```

Comment: Actually, I setted up a `StateMachine` for all the states, which there is no problem about it. The only problem is that the text won't show up. Even if I change the font size, opacity, color or put it in `main.lua`, nothing happens. You tried.

Comment: There is something blocking love from accessing the function, maybe check the stack traceback for that function and make sure its accessed from the love draw callback.

If that still doesn't work, I don't know what would, you know your code better than I do